# How to set an object to an nested Dictionary or Array in plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, plist

I am trying to set values to a plist. The Plist either contains an Array or a Dictionary. The Dictionary or Array can hold multible Arrays or Dictionarys within Dictionarys and Arrays.
So the structure is like this;

```
<key>Dictionary</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Dictionary-2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Array</key>
            <array>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Test</key>
                        <string></string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

So eg. I like to change the string Test, how do I do this? When I make MutableDictionarys and MutableArrays I can set the object at index. But then I would need to replace every other dictionary and array with the new dictionary and array.

Is there an easyer way? then replacing every object in the dictionary or array?

Answer (score 2):

When reading the property list with `propertyListWithData:options:format:error:`,
you can set the `NSPropertyListMutableContainers` option.

Then the returned property list has mutable arrays and dictionaries, so that you can
just replace an inner object, for example

```
plist[@"key1"][@"key2"][0][@"Test"] = @"new value;
```

With the `NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves` option, you could even 
*modify* the values, for example:

```
[plist[@"key1"][@"key2"][0][@"Test"] appendString:@"..."];
```

If you don't know if the intermediate nodes exist or not then you would
have to create them if necessary, for example:

```
if (plist[@"key1"] == nil)
    plist[@"key1"] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
if (plist[@"key1"][@"key2"] == nil)
    plist[@"key1"][@"key2"] = [NSMutableArray array];
if ([plist[@"key1"][@"key2"] count] == 0)
    plist[@"key1"][@"key2"][0] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

plist[@"key1"][@"key2"][0][@"Test"] = @"new value";
```

Comment: ok, but what if the I don't know the structure of the plist file. Can I not just make [self.plistDict setObject:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(id<NSCopying>)#>]; to set an object to a subdirectory of the root directory?

Comment: @DavidG.: If you don't know if the intermediate dictionaries/arrays already exist then you have to check that first and create them only if necessary. Otherwise you would overwrite existing nodes.